# The terminology of the group $a^ib^j$ for $0\leq i < m$ and $0\leq j < n$, i.e. $a^m=1$ and $b^n=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

Suppose I have a group that consists of all elements of type $a^ib^j$ for $0\leq i < m$ and $0\leq j < n$, i.e. $a^m=1$ and $b^n=1$. Here are my questions:

1) What are $a$ and $b$ called?

2) What are $m$ and $n$ called?

Any other basic related terminology I should know for this case?

Comment: Do you mean "generator" for (1) and "order" for (2)?

Comment: Not sure, that's why I'm asking :)
Does the term generator apply even if there is more than one, like in the case above, a and b?

Comment: Yes. A group can have more than one generator. And in your case, $\{a,b\}$ can be said to be a generating set of the group.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a specific terms for this type of group, i.e. is it called cyclic or something?

Comment: "Finitely generated" group

Comment: Please post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I apologize, and I thank you for the useful advice and input.

Comment: You're welcome. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks, I did. I wouldn't mind asking as a separate question, but it appears I am not allowed to ask questions any more, maybe if my downvotes were cancelled, we could remedy this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here $a$ and $b$ are *generators* of the group and $m$ and $n$ are the *orders* of the generators $a$ and $b$, respectively.

Assuming $a$ and $b$ commute, a potential [presentation for the group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) is $$\langle a, b\mid a^m, b^n, ab=ba\rangle.$$

Comment: Well spotted, @MikeEarnest; thank you! I've edited my answer now.

Comment: Let's have a specific example, say for example we are looking at remainders modulo 6, what would be the generators for such a group? I.e. minimal, optimal set of generators. Or how about the case with 10?

Comment: Sorry, I meant under multiplication, not addition.

Comment: Also, speaking of separate group, can you please look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863572/group-theory-terminology-action-of-a-group? I was not able to google the exact wording, and for some reason got a downvote already :(

Comment: I suggest you ask that as a new question, @BaronYugovich.

Comment: I've commented on your other question, @BaronYugovich.

Comment: I am trying to ask the case about mod 6 as a separate question, but I got banned from asking. Can you please lift my ban, or at least answer my question here? Thank a lot!

Comment: I changed one of my downvotes to an upvote, @BaronYugovich. The ban might be lifted now.