# What can I say about $a$ and $b$, that they belong to the same class when $G$ acts on $S$, same category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

Suppose I have a set $S$,  and a group $G$, and let $a$ and $b$ be in S, $g$ in $G$, and $g*a=b$. What can I say about $a$ and $b$, that they belong to the same class when $G$ acts on $S$, same category? How can say something like $G$ divides $S$ into equivalence classes, and $a$ and $b$ are in the same class?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please ask *one* question at a time.

Comment: Sorry, but for some reason I got banned from asking questions and I can't even ask any more. Can you please give me some info on the questions I've already asked, so I can learn something? I am not allowed to ask new questions anyway, this is my last try. Thanks.

Comment: It's because you've got too many downvotes.

Comment: I think this is a borderline case, context-wise. If the user is attempting to find the right words for these things, possibly because they are not sure what the English equivalents are, it's not clear what more context is necessary. As for the focus of the question, I don't think there's a big problem with there being "more than one" question either. They're are two and they're pretty closely related. I would rather *not* have a separate post for the second question.

Comment: Thanks rschwieb. I also feel like it's simpler to explain the terms together, in one illustrating sentence, given that they are closely related.
It's also a bit of a chicken and egg problem now, even if I want to ask it as separate question, I can't because I got banned.

Comment: @BaronYugovich At any rate, hopefully you have your answer, even if the question is closed and/or deleted.

Comment: Hi @Shaun: I can appreciate your reasons for the criticisms above, but it seems IMO in this case possibly to be a too-rigid application both of those criteria. Possibly the newbie is being bitten too hard. Please bear this in mind in future cases. Thanks

Comment: @BaronYugovich And it would be good to follow up on Shaun's advice anyway, to help learn how to insulate your questions from negative attention due to what we call "lack of context" around here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I thought it was embarassingly basic question, I did not know what context to give. Maybe you can help me by showing me what would've been the right way to ask this question?

Comment: @BaronYugovich Well, it isn't exactly clear that you do need more in this case. It's a little puzzling how you came to ask the question in the first place, when this definition is given in most basic group theory texts. It would be unusual to come up with this question on one's own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that $a$ and $b$ are in the same *orbit* of that group action.

Yes, orbits partition the set being acted upon (in this case, $G$.)